# Merge arrays with same values

Tags: php, arrays, siblings, array-merge

I have an array on input with ids of graphic elements and I need to find groups of them. I was trying to use array_search and array_marge but without success.

I have array of siblings:

```
'siblings' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 1
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 2
          1 => int 3
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 3
          1 => int 5
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 6
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 7
      5 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 6
          1 => int 7
```

I need output like following:

```
'groups' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 0
          1 => int 1
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 2
          1 => int 3
          2 => int 5
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 4
          1 => int 6
          2 => int 7
```

I can output this by following:

```
    $groups[] = array_unique(array_merge($siblings[0]));
    $groups[] = array_unique(array_merge($siblings[1],$siblings[2]));
    $groups[] = array_unique(array_merge($siblings[3],$siblings[4],$siblings[5]));

    var_dump($groups); // will output the previous output of groups
```

But I need function that will work on large scale.

Comment: How are you determining groups?  I might assume that you want groups of 3, but then why does the first group in your example only have 2?

Comment: Groups are array that contains merged arrays of siblings. If one of the value from siblings array is present in other array these arrays should be merged.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be so efficient but it works. The normal idea is loop through the array, check the intersection of the current with the remaining inner arrays. If there is some intersection, just merge them into the current, otherwise prepare the next arrays set (to loop and extract the next group):

```
$a = array('siblings' =>  array(array(0,1),array(2,3),array(3,5),
                                array(4,6),array(4,7),array(6,7)));
$g[] = $a["siblings"][0];
$round = array_slice($a["siblings"],1);
$temp = array();
$i = 0;

while(count($round) > 0){
  $v = array_shift($round);
  if(count(array_intersect($g[$i],$v)) > 0) 
      $g[$i] = array_unique(array_merge($g[$i],$v));
  else $temp[] = $v;
  if(count($round) == 0 && count($temp) > 0) {
    $g[] = $temp[0]; 
    $i++;
    $round = array_slice($temp,1);
    $temp = array();
  }
}
$groups["groups"] = $g;
var_dump($groups);
```

Result:

```
array(1) { 
   ["groups"]=> array(3) {
                [0]=> array(2) { 
                       [0]=> int(0) 
                       [1]=> int(1) } 
                [1]=> array(3) { 
                       [0]=> int(2) 
                       [1]=> int(3) 
                       [3]=> int(5) } 
                [2]=> array(3) { 
                       [0]=> int(4) 
                       [1]=> int(6) 
                       [2]=> int(7) } } }
```

Comment: using `array_pop` may be better than `array_shift` in this case. The idea is get and remove each element from `$round`. However the order of output elements will change (although I think it should not matter).

Comment: @user3173246 nice to know that, if it helped, please accept the answer (by clicking on the gray tick mark). I know you're new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work.  It doesn't compare siblings against each other.  Instead it flattens the array, removes duplicates and then breaks it into groups of 3.

```
<?php

$siblings = array(
    array(0, 1),
    array(2, 3),
    array(3, 5),
    array(4, 6),
    array(4, 7),
    array(6, 7),
);

$merged = array();
$grouped = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($siblings); $i++) {
    array_push($merged, $siblings[$i][0]);
    array_push($merged, $siblings[$i][1]);
}

$merged = array_unique($merged);
$merged = array_chunk($merged, 3);

print_r($merged);

?>
```

Gives the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )

)
```